# syntax for getting dynamically made property in state

Tags: reactjs

I have a state where i have made dynamic properties inside it, like

```
option_0:'opt1',
option_1:'opt2
```

where `opt1` and `opt2` are dynamically fetched. The whole state after user input etc, comes out like this::

```
{
  options_number:4,
  options_0:'opt1',
  options_1:'opt2',
}
```

and so on.
I want to console log the value of each of the dynamic values, where i have stored the options number. so i am doing like:

```
for(var _options_number=0; _options_number<=this.state.options_number; _options_number++){
  console.log(this.state[`options_`+${_options_number}])
}
```

but it is giving `NaN` or `undefined`, after minor syntax experimentation. Please let me know thw correct syntax to get the value of each dynamically made state property (eg. `this.state.options_`  ..)

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var _options_number=0; _options_number<=this.state.options_number; _options_number++){
  console.log(this.state[`options_${_options_number}`])
}
```

You are closing the ` before.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps else you have to be more specific about how you store your dynamically fetched states.

```js
class Testing extends React.Component{

   constructor(props){
    super(props); 
    this.state={
      option_0:'opt1',
      option_1:'opt2'
    }
   }
   
   componentDidMount(){
    for (const item in this.props.options) {
      console.log(`Value for options_${item} is: `)
      console.log(this.state[`option_${item}`])
    }
   }
   
   render(){
    return( 
      <div>Check console </div>
    )
   }
}


class App extends React.Component{
  
  render(){
    return(
    
      <Testing options={{0:'opt1', 1:'opt2'}} />
    
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <App />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```